# Symfony2 form_label raw

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I want to render raw translation, so I decided to yous 'raw' option in twig template. But it doesn't work. Example:

```
{{ form_label(form.sfGuardUserProfile.roules_acceptance) | raw }}
```

On my website I will see this:

```
Accept the <a href="url_to_pdf">terms</a>
```

And I don't want to see HTML code, I want to see the link. How to show raw label of form?

Comment: An you add the expected output? Why not just use `form_label`?

Comment: Because in my translation I have the link to the terms in pdf, this link is escaped you can't clicked because you see html code on the site. And I want link not html code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

reading here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

if the name of your field is lets say    product[name]   you can overwrite the label block just for the individual field:

```
{% block _product_name_label %}
     <label>{{ label|raw }}</label>
{% endblock %}
```

or for example:

```
{% block _product_name_label %}
     <label>Accept the <a href="url_to_pdf">terms</a></label>
{% endblock %}
```

just put the code in the template where you render the form and add

```
{% form_theme form _self %}
```

so the rendering engine will search for overwritten blocks in the same file first

you can find the default template file in \vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Resources\views\Form\form_div_layout.html.twig if you use full stack framework.

Answer (score 1):

I have also try this: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/autoescape.html

```
{% autoescape false %}
    Everything will be outputted as is in this block
{% endautoescape %}
```

But it doesn't work. Why? Because when you use form_label() function Symfony use \vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Resources\views\Form\form_div_layout.html.twig and this block:

```
    {% block form_label %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {% if label is not sameas(false) %}
            {% if not compound %}
                {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'for': id}) %}
            {% endif %}
            {% if required %}
                {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'class': (label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' required')|trim}) %}
            {% endif %}
            {% if label is empty %}
                {% set label = name|humanize %}
            {% endif %}
            <label{% for attrname, attrvalue in label_attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}>{{ label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</label>
        {% endif %}
    {% endspaceless %}
    {% endblock form_label %}
```

I can try:

```
{{ form_label(form.sfGuardUserProfile.roules_acceptance) | raw }}
```

but raw option will be override in form_div_layout.html.twig. And I finally decided to made this:

```
{{ 'form.roules_acceptance'| trans | raw }}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you did?

Comment: I edited my post, maybe it will help if not explain me what you do not understand. I will try help.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up by the following as I want to keep the behaviour of the form_div_layout so I just:

```
{%- block form_label -%}
    {% set label %}{{ label|raw }}{% endset %}
    {{ parent() }}
{%- endblock -%}
```

and that works the extended version looks like this to handle translation and so correctly:

```
{% use 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}

{%- block form_label -%}
    {# Set label to raw label #}
    {% if label is not same as (false) %}
        {% set label %}
            {%- if translation_domain is same as (false) -%}
                {{ label|raw }}
            {%- else -%}
                {{- label|trans({}, translation_domain)|raw }}
            {%- endif -%}
        {% endset %}
    {%- endif -%}

    {# Avoid call of translation again %}
    {% set translation_domain = false %}

    {# Call default behaviour from form_div_layout.html.twig #}
    {{- parent() -}}
{%- endblock -%}
```